# Who wins out of css top/bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, css, position

If you have a div that sits at the 'bottom' like so:

```
<div id="box" style="position: absolute;width: 10px;height: 10px;bottom: 0px;"></div>
```

and then if you were to change the position using 'top'...

```
$('#box').css({'top':'0px'});
```

what happens to the 'bottom' css command and what decides who (top or bottom) wins?

Should I cancel bottom somehow at the same time as setting top?

Ideas:

```
$('#box').css({'top':'0px','bottom','none'});
$('#box').css({'top':'0px','bottom',''});
```

It never occurred to me before

Comment: who wins? ==> http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/N7yGb/

Comment: Why does top win? Does jquery swap the order (so that the command is last)? Say if I again set bottom would bottom come last (overwriting top)?

Comment: @nietonfir: I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean. They're on two different positioning axes, one vertical and one horizontal.

Comment: @BoltClock What I wanted to say is that the usual order in CSS shorthand notation somehow also applies to a positioning precedence. 'bottom/right' cannot "override"/reposition an element if 'top/left' are set.

Comment: @nietonfir: Well in your first comment it says right > ... > left but what you just said shows otherwise, so...

Comment: @BoltClock \*zomfg\* you beat me to it! ;-) Removed! thx…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interactions between width, height, and box offsets in a variety of scenarios in CSS are all detailed in [section 10](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html) of the spec.

Since your element is absolutely positioned, refer to [section 10.6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height), which says:

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> > 'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block
>
> If all three of 'top', 'height', and 'bottom' are auto, set 'top' to the static position and apply rule number three below.
>
> If none of the three are 'auto': If both 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values. If one of 'margin-top' or 'margin-bottom' is 'auto', solve the equation for that value. If the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for 'bottom' and solve for that value.

In your case, because the values are over-constrained once you set a value for `top`, `top` wins.

Note that setting `none` won't work because it's not a valid value for `bottom`, and setting the empty string reverts it to its default value which for most if not all elements is `auto`, which does not result in over-constrained values.

Comment: hmm... I'm not sure I like the notion of a default winner. So just to be clear, my further question would be: If I am not using top (but it is set), can I ether remove it from my css or set it to auto?

Comment: @BENZ.404: Yes, if you want it to be anchored to the bottom.

Comment: Very interesting stuff!

Answer (score 1):

**Top** "wins" when all three of `top`, `bottom` and `height` are present - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom):

> ...the top property overrides the bottom property, so if top is not auto, the computed value of bottom is the negative of the computed value of top.