# What is the correct way to define a CSS Position interface in Typescript?

Tags: css, typescript

As you know, effective CSS absolute positioning can be achieved by setting `top left`, `top right`, `bottom left` or `bottom right`. ([false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52695436/3750762))

What is the best way to reflect this requirement in Typescript?

Here's my go at it:

```js
interface TopLeft {

    top: number,
    left: number

}

interface TopRight {

    top: number,
    right: number

}

interface BottomLeft {

    bottom: number,
    left: number

}

interface BottomRight {

    bottom: number,
    right: number

}


type Position = TopLeft | TopRight | BottomLeft | BottomRight;
```

**Note:** Bear in mind I'm using the `number` type instead of the `string` type as I'll always be expecting absolute positioning values in pixels.

Is there, perhaps, a simpler way?

Comment: I'd like to know why I am being downvoted.

Comment: Because CSS is not a TypeScript concern. If your TypeScript knows about CSS classes or positions then you are really breaking separation of concerns rules.

Comment: What if you're absolutely positioning an element in a page programmatically? Should this be done in CSS? No, _that_ would break the separation of concerns.

Hell, I could be writing a CSS compiler in Typescript for all that matters. Separation of concerns has no play here.

Comment: "What is the best way...." questions tend to be opinion based and are considered off topic. There really is no, one, definitive answer to your question.

Comment: Questions are not opinion-based, answers are. Usually, asking the question helps clarify if it indeed _has_ or _hasn't_ got a definitive answer.

Comment: "As you know, effective CSS absolute positioning can be achieved by setting top left, top right, bottom left or bottom right." Depending on what you mean by "effective", this is either inherently subjective (I've used various combinations of zero, one, three or four offsets to great "effect"), or outright hogwash (because all of them actually work - CSS makes sure of this). The rest of the question would probably benefit from the removal of this statement entirely. And a change from "best" to something more specific.

Comment: people just take things too serious. I upvoted your question, I think it's a perfectly valid question

Comment: @BoltClock Effective as in _valid_. However upon further inspection, it's not a must for CSS, since it assumes the other properties are `auto` if undefined, therefore those combinations are not CSS specific requirements.

@SergioAlen I do agree, though I understand the need for some organization in a community of this size.

Comment: @undefined: Based on this knowledge I think I can answer your question with something that's not opinion-based. Maybe you should keep that statement in your question after all.

Comment: I'd gladly look over it, however maybe the question would benefit from a more abstract take. Something along the lines of Typescript Interfaces with a white-list of possible property combinations. Then again, who on earth would search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you know, effective CSS absolute positioning can be achieved by setting `top left`, `top right`, `bottom left` or `bottom right`.

This is a false premise. If "effective" means "valid", CSS ensures that absolute positioning will work no matter what combination of offsets you specify. If an absposed element has none of these values specified (i.e. they all default to auto), [it will remain in its static position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968979/what-are-the-default-top-left-botton-or-right-values-when-positionabsolute-is/19969046#19969046). If it has *one* of these values set to something else, it will be offset in that direction alone. It doesn't "require" two of them to be offset, and it can use more than two, [with compensation for overconstrained values where appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856233/who-wins-out-of-css-top-bottom/23856282#23856282).

If you only intend to *support* absolute positioning using corner offsets, what you have is fine. But if you want your API to match the spec as closely as possible with all available options, support all possible combinations by defining a single interface, and converting undefined values to `auto` or leaving them out (depending on how your script actually sets these values):

```
interface CSSPositionOffsets {
    top: number,
    right: number,
    bottom: number,
    left: number
}

type Position = CSSPositionOffsets;
```

Comment: _If you only intend to support absolute positioning using corner offsets, what you have is fine._ Obviously, as [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694880/what-is-the-correct-way-to-define-a-css-position-interface-in-typescript/52695436#comment92317227_52694880) my intention was to learn about typescript and property combinations, but then again, that's my fault for not abstracting it enough. I'll take your answer since it's the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to reflect this requirement in Typescript?

In my opinion your solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: What if instead of 4 combinations I had 50, would this still be a valid approach? Is there a solution to this issue?